# Spark Cluster starting issue

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing, iptables

I'm new to spark, and trying to setup spark cluster. I did following things to set-up and check status of spark cluster, but not sure about status.

I tried to check  master-ip:8081 (8080, 4040, 4041) in the browser, but didn't see any results. To start with, I set-up  and started hadoop cluster.

```
 JPS gives:

 2436 SecondaryNameNode
 2708 NodeManager
 2151 NameNode
 5495 Master
 2252 DataNode
 2606 ResourceManager
 5710 Jps
```

Question (Was it necessary to start hadoop?)

In Master /usr/local/spark/conf/slaves

```
 localhost
 slave-node-1
 slave-node-2
```

Now, to start Spark; Master Started with

```
  $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh
```

And tested with

```
  ps -ef|grep spark
  hduser    5495     1  0 18:12 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/local/java/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/*:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/ -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --host master-hostname --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
```

On slave node 1

```
 $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://205.147.102.19:7077
```

Tested with

```
 ps -ef|grep spark
 hduser    1847     1 20 18:24 pts/0    00:00:04 /usr/local/java/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://master-ip:7077
```

Same on slave-node 2

```
  $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://master-ip:7077
  ps -ef|grep spark
  hduser    1948     1  3 18:18 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/local/java/bin/java -cp /usr/local/spark/conf/:/usr/local/spark/jars/* -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --webui-port 8081 spark://master-ip:7077
```

I was not able to see anything on the web console of spark.. so I thought problem may be with firewall. Here is my iptables..

```
  iptables -L -nv
  Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  6136  587K fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22
  151K   25M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  6   280 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  579 34740 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  34860 2856K ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  145  7608 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
  56156 5994K REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
  0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
  0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8081

  Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
  pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3531 packets, 464K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

 Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 2   120 REJECT     all  --  *      *       218.87.109.153       0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
 5794  554K RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I'm trying all I can to see if spark-cluster is set-up and how to check it properly. And if cluster is set-up, why am I not able to check that on web-console? What could be wrong? Any pointers would be helpful...

EDIT - ADDING LOGS after spark-shell --master local command (in the master)

```
 17/01/11 18:12:46 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO master.Master: Starting Spark master at spark://master:7077
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO master.Master: Running Spark version 2.1.0
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @3326ms
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started   o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@20f0b5ff{/app,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@734e74b2{/app/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1bc45d76{/,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6a274a23{/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4f5d45d5{/static,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4fb65368{/app/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@76208805{/driver/kill,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@258dbadd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.Server: Started @3580ms
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO ui.MasterWebUI: Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://master:8080
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.2.z-SNAPSHOT
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1cfbb7e9{/,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.ServerConnector: Started ServerConnector@2f7af4e{HTTP/1.1}{master:6066}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO server.Server: Started @3628ms
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service on port 6066.
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO rest.StandaloneRestServer: Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@799d5f4f{/metrics/master/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@647c46e3{/metrics/applications/json,null,AVAILABLE}
 17/01/11 18:12:47 INFO master.Master: I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
```

In  slave nodes-

```
 17/01/11 18:22:46 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master:7077...
 17/01/11 18:22:46 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master:7077
```

Tonnes of java errors..

```
 17/01/11 18:31:18 ERROR Worker: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark Web UI start when you are creating SparkContext

Try to run `spark-shell --master yourmaster:7077` and then open Spark UI. You can also use `spark-sumit` to submit some application, then SparkContext will be created.

Example `spark-submit`, from Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html):

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --supervise \
  --executor-memory 20G \
  --total-executor-cores 100 \
  /path/to/examples.jar \
  1000
```

Answer to first question: you must start Hadoop components if you want to use HDFS or YARN. If not, they can be not started

Also you can go to `/etc/hosts/` and remove line with 127.0.0.1 or set `MASTER_IP` variable in Spark configuration to proper host name

Comment: Did  spark-shell --master local (in the maser), Got message saying that Spark context Web UI available at http://master-ip:4040...  But when opened browser, not showing anything... So my question is spark cluster started? And are slave-1, and slave-2 part of cluster? If so, how do i confirm? And finally what could be wrong with web-console?

Comment: Please check edits.. I guess issue could be iptables, cluster didn't start i guess. because of iptables...  but i'm still unable to understand why I can't see the webconsole...

Comment: I feel problem could of iptables/networking.. I did append this - ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:7077 to iptables, and still log says it can't connect to master with specified ip addresss... any thoughts?

Comment: @user1478061 Stop iptables for tests and see if Spark is working ok. If not, please see my edit - set MASTER_IP and remove localhost's IPs from `/etc/hosts`

Comment: The culprit was as expected IP tables... I just tried to run tomcat, and when it too failed to run, i realized time for me to fix iptables.. Thanks so much! your discussion helped me a lot! I can now access webconsle and everything else.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was IP tables. most other things were fine. So I just followed instructions here https://wiki.debian.org/iptables to fix IP tables, and it worked for me. Only thing that you should know which ports will be used for spark/hadoop etc. I opened 8080, 54310, 50070, 7077 (some defaults used by many for hadoop and spark installation)...